# Align tables perfectly using vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify and i have four data tables. I want to put two data tables side by side with a bit of white space between them. I am using v-flex and v-layout row wrap and i am putting all the tables between them. But i am getting the desired result. The first two tables are up and down and the other two are fine but there is no space between them. How should i fix it?

```js
<template>

<div>
    
<v-toolbar card prominent color="primary" dark>
<v-toolbar-title>Add Countries</v-toolbar-title>
</v-toolbar>
 <v-form>
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row wrap>

        <v-flex xs12 sm6>
          <v-text-field
            label="Country Name"
            single-line
            solo
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex xs12 sm6>
          <v-text-field
            label="Currency Code"
            single-line
            solo
          ></v-text-field>
        </v-flex>


      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>

  <!-- Region -->
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs6>
   <v-toolbar flat color="white">
      <v-toolbar-title>Region</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2" v-on="on">Add</v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-text>
            <v-container grid-list-md>
              <v-layout wrap>
                <v-flex >
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.region" label="Region"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-container>
          </v-card-text>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="close">Cancel</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="save">Save</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-toolbar>
     <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="regions"
      class="elevation-1" 
    >
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.region }}</td>
        
        <td class="justify-right layout px-10">
          <v-icon
            small
            class="mr-2"
            @click="editItem(props.item)"
          >
            edit
          </v-icon>
          <v-icon
            small
            @click="deleteItem(props.item)"
          >
            delete
          </v-icon>
        </td>
      </template>
    
   <!-- <template slot="no-data">
  <center>
    <h3 id="regionAlert">Add Regions</h3>
  </center>
</template> -->
    </v-data-table>
  </v-flex>

      
    <!-- Income Groups -->
    
    <v-flex xs6>
     <v-toolbar flat color="white" class="mt-5">
      <v-toolbar-title>Income Groups</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2" v-on="on">Add</v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-text>
            <v-container grid-list-md>
              <v-layout wrap>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.income" label="Income Groups"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-container>
          </v-card-text>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <!-- <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="close1">Cancel</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="save1">Save</v-btn> -->
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-toolbar>
     <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="income"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        
        <td class="justify-center layout px-0">
          <v-icon
            small
            class="mr-2"
            @click="editItem(props.item)"
          >
            edit
          </v-icon>
          <v-icon
            small
            @click="deleteItem(props.item)"
          >
            delete
          </v-icon>
        </td>
      </template>
    
    </v-data-table>
     </v-flex>

    


  <!-- Races -->
  <v-flex xs6>
   <v-toolbar flat color="white" class="mt-5">
      <v-toolbar-title>Race</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2" v-on="on">Add</v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-text>
            <v-container grid-list-md>
              <v-layout wrap>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.race" label="Race"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-container>
          </v-card-text>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <!-- <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="close1">Cancel</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="save1">Save</v-btn> -->
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-toolbar>
     <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="race"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        
        <td class="justify-center layout px-0">
          <v-icon
            small
            class="mr-2"
            @click="editItem(props.item)"
          >
            edit
          </v-icon>
          <v-icon
            small
            @click="deleteItem(props.item)"
          >
            delete
          </v-icon>
        </td>
      </template>
    
    </v-data-table>
  </v-flex>
<v-divider></v-divider>

    <!-- Age Groups -->
    <v-flex xs6>
 <v-toolbar flat color="white" class="mt-5">
      <v-toolbar-title>Age Groups</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2" v-on="on">Add</v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
          </v-card-title>

          <v-card-text>
            <v-container grid-list-md>
              <v-layout wrap>
                <v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
                  <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.age" label="Age Group"></v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
              </v-layout>
            </v-container>
          </v-card-text>

          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <!-- <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="close1">Cancel</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" flat @click="save1">Save</v-btn> -->
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </v-toolbar>
     <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="age"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template v-slot:items="props">
        <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        
        <td class="justify-center layout px-0">
          <v-icon
            small
            class="mr-2"
            @click="editItem(props.item)"
          >
            edit
          </v-icon>
          <v-icon
            small
            @click="deleteItem(props.item)"
          >
            delete
          </v-icon>
        </td>
      </template>
    
    </v-data-table>
    </v-flex>
</v-layout>

</div>
    
</template>


<script>
 export default {
    data (){
      return {
      dialog: false,
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Name',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },
       
      { text: 'Actions', value: 'name', sortable: false }
      ],
      regions: [],
      income: [],
      race: [],
      age: [],
      editedIndex: -1,
      editedItem: {
        name: '',
      },
      defaultItem: {
        name: '',
      }
    };
    },

    computed: {
      formTitle () {
        return this.editedIndex === -1 ? 'New Item' : 'Edit Item'
      }
    },

    watch: {
      dialog (val) {
        val || this.close()
      }
    },

    created () {
      this.initialize()
    },

    methods: {
      initialize () {
        this.regions = [
           {
            region: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            
          },
        ]

        this.race = [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
           
          },
          
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            
          }
        ]
        this.income = [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            
          },
          
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
           
          }
        ]

        this.age = [
           {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
           
          },
          
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
           
          }
        ]
      },

      editItem (item) {
        this.editedIndex = this.desserts.indexOf(item)
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
        this.dialog = true
      },

      deleteItem (item) {
        const index = this.regions.indexOf(item)
        confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?') && this.regions.splice(index, 1)
      },

      close () {
        this.dialog = false
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
          this.editedIndex = -1
        }, 300)
      },

      save () {
        if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
          Object.assign(this.regions[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem)
        } else {
          this.regions.push(this.editedItem)
        }
        this.close()
      }
    }
  }
</script>


<style scoped>
#regionAlert
{
     font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 13px;
}
</style>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb9ye.png)

Comment: Can you generate the same in the jsFiddle?

Comment: I was adding margin top to the second table which was causing this issue